# how to Change the file Attribute from read-only to read/write using Python?

Tags: file, python-2.7, attributes, readonly, read-write

I have a bunch of files which have read-only status. It is not possible to change the status manual so I was thinking of a code that I could say change the status of all the files in one folder from read-only. However, I can't find the right coding. Is the python helpful for this case?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I have already tried this one though it does not work. What do you think is the problem?                  **** import os, shutil, stat
K=os.chdir("W:/50_SdiCad/40_Process/existing_dgn/Python")
os.chmod(K, stat.S_IWRITE)  ******

Comment: Tell your OS. Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need of python here. You could simply type the below written command in the terminal:
chmod -R 777 foldername           (777 is just for example)

If you want to stick with python, type the following in the python interpreter:

> import subprocess
>
> subprocess.call(['chmod', '-R', '777', 'foldername'])